# Javascript not inserting input

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I've been trying to use stripe to accept payment and I've been trying to make a rough prototype for it from a guide I found but I can't seem to get it working. The new input named "stripeToken" never inserts after the submit. This causes my PHP script to never execute. I'm trying to understand why it never inserts. Here's the scripts:

Javascript:  (In the head of page)

```
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('mykeyishere');
    </script>
    <script>
        // Event Listeners
        $('#payment-form').on('submit', generateToken);

        var generateToken = function (e) {
            var form = $(this);

            // No pressing the buy now button more than once
            form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

            // Create the token, based on the form object
            Stripe.create(form, stripeResponseHandler);

            // Prevent the form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    </script>
```

HTML/Javascript: (Tried JS both in the head and in the form)

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                <script>
                    var stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
                        var form = $('#payment-form');

                        // Any validation errors?
                        if (response.error) {
                            // Show the user what they did wrong
                            form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);

                            // Make the submit clickable again
                            form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                        } else {
                            // Otherwise, we're good to go! Submit the form.

                            // Insert the unique token into the form
                            $('<input>', {
                                'type': 'hidden',
                                'name': 'stripeToken',
                                'value': response.id
                            }).appendTo(form);

                            // Call the native submit method on the form
                            // to keep the submission from being canceled
                            form.get(0).submit();
                        }
                    };</script>
                <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Card Number</span>
                        <input type="text" data-stripe="number">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <label>
                        <span>CVC</span>
                        <input type="text" data-stripe="cvc">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" data-stripe="exp-month">
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" data-stripe="exp-year">
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove that script tag from inside the form and put it next to the other script tag.

also try wrapping your event binding in a document.ready

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#payment-form').on('submit', generateToken);
     var stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
                        var form = $('#payment-form');

                        // Any validation errors?
                        if (response.error) {
                            // Show the user what they did wrong
                            form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);

                            // Make the submit clickable again
                            form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                        } else {
                            // Otherwise, we're good to go! Submit the form.

                            // Insert the unique token into the form
                            $('<input>', {
                                'type': 'hidden',
                                'name': 'stripeToken',
                                'value': response.id
                            }).appendTo(form);

                            // Call the native submit method on the form
                            // to keep the submission from being canceled
                            form.get(0).submit();
                        }
                    };
            var generateToken = function (e) {
                var form = $(this);

                // No pressing the buy now button more than once
                form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

                // Create the token, based on the form object
                Stripe.create(form, stripeResponseHandler);

                // Prevent the form from submitting
                e.preventDefault();
            };


    });
```

From what I can guess ( and its not a good guess), is that the #payment-form does not get bound correctly because the script is getting ran before the dom is ready?

Also another thing caught my eye.  You have e.preventDefault() which stops the form from being submitted, but then you have a responsehandler.  does that response handler get called? Is there some request that goes out to stripe and comes back?

Check in your network window and see if that is happening.  The form only gets submitted in the form.get(0).submit(); part of the response handler, so after stripe completes.

Comment: I put it back in the head by the other script. It still didn't work. I also opened up the network menu on the developer mode but I'm not extremely familiar with JS so I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for. For the other part, yes. On submit Stripe.js processes the information, and sends a token back and puts an input into the form and executes the form.